# Optimising a Prolog Rule

Tags: prolog

I have the following Prolog Rule:

```
p(X,Y):- q(Y,X), r(Y), s(Y), t(X).
```

It is known that `r(Y)` and `s(Y)` have only one solution, while `q(X,Y)` and `p(X,Y)` have several solutions.

The task is to optimise the Rule with an auxillary predicate.

My guess is to put a Cut between `s(Y)` and `t(X)` to prevent useless backtracking.

What kind of auxillary predicate could one write to optimise this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be cautious with cuts. For example if - on your first try - you have choosen the right `Y` but the wrong `X` (for `t(X)`) using a cut in the predicates body will provide a wrong answer.

Example:

```
r(1).
s(1).
t(X):- member(X,[7,8,9,6]).
q(Y,X):- member(X,[1,2,3,6]), member(Y,[3,4,5,6,1]).

p(X,Y):- q(Y,X), r(Y), s(Y), t(X).

?- p(X,Y).
X = 6,
Y = 1.
```

But with

```
p(X,Y):- q(Y,X), r(Y), s(Y), !, t(X).

?- p(X,Y).
false.
```

If you are using the cut within the aux predicate the cut does not discard 'right' answers because the backtracking is still allowed in the predictae `p/2` even if `aux/2` was passed once:

```
aux(Y) :- r(Y), s(Y), !.
p(X,Y):- q(Y,X), aux(Y), t(X).

?- p(X,Y).
X = 6,
Y = 1.
```

---

I just saw that there is no improvement by using the aux predicate. However using

```
aux(Y) :- r(Y), !, s(Y).
```

or

```
aux(Y) :- !, r(Y), s(Y).
```

might improve the speed if `s/1` is computative expensive. The second solution should only be used if `Y` was instantiated before. Also reordering the predicates could result in a speed up.

Comment: So did I understand it correctly, that the Cut in the middle of ``aux/1`` prevents further backtracking for the subgoal ``s(Y)`` once ``r(Y)`` evaluated to true? And that ``aux/1`` doesnt prevent backtracking in ``p(X,Y)``?

Comment: @gython correct. The cut works for the current predicate only.